# how to get length of integers in PHP ?

Tags: php, integer

I want to get the length of integer values for validation in PHP.
Example:
Mobile numbers should be only 10 integer values. It should not be more than 10 or less than 10 and also it should not be included of alphabetic characters.

How can I validate this?

Comment: Cell phone numbers should be represented as strings. They are not numbers. It makes no sense to add them, multiply them, divide them etc.

Comment: If you are going to use the phone numbers to make calls, let the library you are using do the validation. If you will not be making calls, don't bother too much with validation. It's easy to over-validate. There are many notations for phone numbers, e.g. `+31 (0)6 12345678` would be a common way to write a dutch cell phone number. Unless you really care, it's better to just store whatever the user entered.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/^\d{10}$/', $string)) {
  // pass
} else {
  // fail
}
```

Comment: Doing $string = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $string); first would make it more allow people to enter spaces and pluses etc without throwing errors.

Comment: This solution has a problem, if the number has 0 in front then it doesn't consider it as 10 digit number, example: 0123456789

Comment: @mimi the regex is working fine with a leading zero, in my case anyway.

Comment: @luke_mclachlan I think mimi is saying that if you have a ten character string of digits that starts with a zero, then you technically have a nine digit number but this code would pass it as a valid ten digit number. <shrug> Whether or not that's actually a problem depends on your application.

Comment: Yeah, OP was asking about phone numbers, which are strings and should be modelled as strings. So I guess just `strlen` would give the length and a regex like this could be used to validate... However there are many ways to write down phone numbers... I don't think validation with a regex is smart.

Answer (score 138):

```
$num_length = strlen((string)$num);
if($num_length == 10) {
    // Pass
} else {
    // Fail
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer.

Comment: If you want to test also negative numbers you can use `$num_length = strlen((string)abs($num))`

Comment: I don't see why this wasn't the accepted answer, it is so straightforward

Answer (score 13):

This will work for almost all cases (except zero) and easily coded in other languages:

```
$length = ceil(log10(abs($number) + 1));
```

Comment: nice, but you missed a parenthesis so $length = ceil(log10(abs($number) + 1)) would be correct.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, the best way is:

```
$length = ceil(log10($number))
```

A decimal logarithm rounded up is equal to length of a number.

Comment: except for 10, 100, 1000 etc.

Comment: except negative numbers :)

Comment: That's a pretty fancy answer. I like it ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a web form, make sure you limit the text input to only hold 10 characters as well to add some accessibility (users don't want to input it wrong, submit, get a dialog about their mistake, fix it, submit again, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Use intval function in loop,
See this example

```
<?php
  $value = 16432;
  $length=0;
  while($value!=0) {
   $value = intval($value/10);
   $length++
  }
  echo "Length of Integer:- ".$length;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = "03432 123-456"; // A mobile number (this would fail)

$number = preg_replace("/^\d/", "", $number);
$length = strlen((string) $number);

if ($number == $input && $length == 10) {
    // Pass
} else {
    // Fail
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are evaluating mobile numbers (phone numbers) then I would recommend not using an int as your chosen data type.  Use a string instead because I cannot forsee how or why you would want to do math with these numbers.  As a best practice, use int, floats, etc, when you want/need to do math.  Use strings when you don't.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, "You want to get the lenght of an integer, the input will not accept alpha numeric data and the lenght of the integer cannot exceed 10. If this is what you mean; In my own opinion, this is the best way to achieve that:"

```
<?php

$int = 1234567890; //The integer variable

    //Check if the variable $int is an integer:
if (!filter_var($int, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) { 
    echo "Only integer values are required!";
    exit();
} else {
    // Convert the integer to array
    $int_array  = array_map('intval', str_split($int));
    //get the lenght of the array
    $int_lenght = count($int_array);
}
    //Check to make sure the lenght of the int does not exceed or less than10
    if ($int_lenght != 10) {
    echo "Only 10 digit numbers are allow!";
    exit();
} else {
     echo $int. " is an integer and its lenght is exactly " . $int_lenght;
    //Then proceed with your code
}

    //This will result to: 1234556789 is an integer and its lenght is exactly 10

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the assertion library of [Webmozart Assert](https://github.com/webmozarts/assert) we can use their build-in methods to validate the input.

- Use `integerish()` to validate that a value casts to an integer
- Use `length()` to validate that a string has a certain number of characters

**Example**

```php
Assert::integerish($input);
Assert::length((string) $input, 10); // expects string, so we type cast to string
```

As all assertions in the Assert class throw an `Webmozart\Assert\InvalidArgumentException` if they fail, we can catch it and communicate a clear message to the user.

**Example**

```php
try {
    Assert::integerish($input);
    Assert::length((string) $input, 10);
} catch (InvalidArgumentException) {
    throw new Exception('Please enter a valid phone number');
}
```

As an extra, it's even possible to check if the value is not a non-negative integer.

**Example**

```php
try {
    Assert::natural($input);
} catch (InvalidArgumentException) {
    throw new Exception('Please enter a valid phone number');
}
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

A bit optimazed answer in 2 or 3 steps depends if we allow negative value

```
if(is_int($number)
&& strlen((string)$number) == 10)
{
   // 1 000 000 000 Executions take from 00:00:00.153200 to 00:00:00.173900
   //Code
}
```

Note that will allow negative up to 9 numbers like -999999999

So if we need skip negatives we need 3rd comparision

```
if(is_int($number)
&& $number >= 0
&& strlen((string)$number) == 10)
{
   // 1 000 000 000 Executions take from 00:00:00.153200
   // to 00:00:00.173900 over 20 tests
}
```

Last case when we want from -1 000 000 000 to 1 000 000 000

```
if(is_int($number)
&& $number >= 0
&& strlen(str_replace('-', '', (string)$number)) == 10)
{
   // 1 000 000 000 Executions take from 00:00:00.153200
   // to 00:00:00.173900 over 20 tests
}
```

For compare
First naswer with regex

```
if (preg_match('/^\d{10}$/', $number)) {
  // Fastest test with 00:00:00.246200
}
```

** Tested at PHP 8.0.12
** XAMPP 3.3.0
** Ryzen 7 2700
** MSI Radeon RX 5700 8G

Tested like

```
$function = function($number)
{
   if(is_int($number)
   && $number >= 0
   && strlen((string)$number) == 10)
   {
      return true;
   }
}

$number = 1000000000;

$startTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true);

for($i = 0; $i < 1000000000; $i++)
{
   call_user_func_array($function, $args);
}

$endTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true);

echo $endTime->diff($startTime)->format('%H:%I:%S.%F');
```